# Не получается парсить все ответы

Tags: java, android, json

Получаю ответ от сервера вида:

```
{"id":"14","text":"Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT Test TEXT ","id_user":"1","status":1}
{"id":"13","text":"Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол Зол ","id_user":"1","status":1}
{"id":"12","text":"Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу Воу ","id_user":"1","status":1}
```

И мне нужно получить значение `text` , это у меня получается, но не совсем так как нужно. Выходит что я получаю значение только первой строки, и все на этом парсинг заканчивается.

```
try 
{
    status = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
    textStory = json.getString(TAG_TEXT);      
    if (status == 1) { //Если от сервера получили status 1 , выводим результат
System.out.println(textStory);
    }
...
}
```

В переменную `textStory` я сохраняю значение **text** из ответа сервера.

Пытался сделать так:

```
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        status = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
         textStory = json.getString(TAG_TEXT);

         if (status == 1) {
             for (int i = 1; i == status; i++) {
                 list.add(textStory); 
                 // Добавляем поочередно каждый элемент в массив
             }
         }
```

Но результат тот же.

Comment: Оба раза непонятно, чем у вас заканчивается блок `try {...`

Comment: @NickVolynkin `} catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }` потом идет метод onPostExecute

Comment: @NickVolynkin получается что парсится только первая строка, и на этом все

Answer (score 1):

```
if (status == 1) {
    for (int i = 1; i == status; i++) {
```

Посмотрите на этот участок кода. Поскольку `status == 1`, то условие в цикле выглядит так:

```
for (int i = 1; i == 1; i++) {
```

И выполняется оно один раз, после чего `i` становится равно `2`.